# memory usage and codes in android

Tags: android, performance, memory, comments

sorry if it's a silly question. Do comments in the java or xml file effect the memory usage of the android application? has anyone tried to monitor the memory usage of his/her application with and without the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments in your code are compiled out and have no effect whatsoever on memory usage in an application.

Answer (score 1):

No, comments do not use any memory.

It's important to understand that, in programming in C, Java, etc. what you're writing is *source code* which, before being run on the computer (or, specifically, your Android device) is compiled into a machine code format. The processor does not run your source code as you see it. The source code you write typically contains lots of stuff like comments (which do NOT have any effect on the actual code) or perhaps things like compiler directives (which may control how the compiler compiles sections of your code).

(I realise it's more correct to use the term *byte code* in the case of Java, but trying to keep the answer simple here.)

An exception to this however would be if you're talking about the case where you insert a file (e.g. XML file) as a **raw resource** within your Android application. But, I think this topic is an advanced one for you to learn about later.